# Preserve comments in pip requirements file after regenerate it

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have the following requirements file:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.10.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
#MySQL-python==1.2.5
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Werkzeug==0.9.6
WTForms==2.0.1
```

But after I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` the commented line (MySQL-python==1.2.5) is replaced

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.10.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
MySQL-python==1.2.5
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Werkzeug==0.9.6
WTForms==2.0.1
```

Is there any way to preserve comments?

Comment: because I wanted in my localhost, but when I uploaded to production I want to remove it.

Comment: Yes I'm using it, and I don't understand you, pip freeze just show packages that my virtualenv is using.

Comment: Never mind, I assumed you weren't using a virtualenv and wanted `MySQL-python` for some other project (and so didn't need it in the requirements for this particular project) :)

Comment: Maybe this question give you more clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670874/workarround-to-make-mysql-works-in-flask-openshift and let you figure out why I want preserve comments in requirements file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `pip freeze -r requirements.txt` which will preserve the order and contents of `requirements.txt` when pip is freezing the installed packages (including comments).

However, it seems that your virtualenv does have `MySQL-python` installed so you'll end up with both a commented and uncommented line for `MySQL-python`. I think you need to either uncomment the line or uninstall `MySQL-python` for "preserving comments" to make sense.

Comment: Inline comments get removed, For example in `mylib==1.1.1 # mylib is needed because..` , the ` # mylib is needed because..` part gets removed.  (comments that are on their own line, survive)